# Getting two touch points on Screen from same View

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been trying to get the coordinates of two touch points on the phone screen from the user. My goal is to ultimately calculate the distance between the two points. So far, I have only found a way to get a single touch point's coordinates as shown below. I realize that I could just replicate the code below twice to achieve my goal, but I would like to avoid creating another touchView as the coordinate system is relative to the position of the touchView.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    float pointx1 = 0f;
    float pointy1 = 0f;

    DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.touchView);

        touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +
                        String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
                pointx1 = event.getX();
                pointy1 = event.getY();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi